# Can someone identify this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Sorry if this is pedantic but I was asked to turn this into a sticker and I just want to verify I am not making something silly. The person asking is clearly not a math specialist.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{8}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^\frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma} dx
$$

In particular I want to make sure that if I translate this exactly as it is, it will be correct. The fraction after e, for example, looks like a power of e as opposed to a multiplier of e.

I myself am not a math expert so any insight on this (possibly whose integral this is) would be very helpful.

Thanks!

PS, it looks like an indefinite integral to me, but what do I know? If this is mis-tagged, just let me know what to tag it as.

Comment: This looks like a Gaussian (but not really): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution. Perhaps it should be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{8}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma}} dx$

Comment: The fraction after $e$ is an exponent. There should be a negative sign in front of the fraction.

Comment: I have no idea why the 8 is there

Comment: "The fraction after e, for example, looks like a power of e as opposed to a multiplier of e." -- If the most reasonable interpretation (i.e. Darius') is correct, it would be a power, not a multiplication. Also, this is not an indefinite integral - it's an improper integral (improper because of the infinite limits, but I believe it would still fall into the category of definite integrals otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gaussian normal-distribution integral is $\large \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma}}\,dx$.

As the comments pointed out, $8$ normally isn't there, and there is a negative in front of the exponent.

Comment: well, maybe they wanted to have an overall area of 8? who knows. 8 isn't even near 1 on the keyboard